# What is wrong with my WPF PasswordBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, passwordbox

I have a login view with a `PasswordBox` marked up as follows:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordText" Width="Auto" Margin="5" PasswordChanged="PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged" />
```

The problem with it is that the caret remains at the extreme left of its text box; it doesn't move forward as you type, so the last character you type ends up the first character in the text box. E.g. when I type the password "123", the content of the `PasswordBox`, after conversion to a normal string, is "321". It is not the conversion code, for if I pre-populate the control with a password, i.e. no typing involved, its content converts to the correct plain string.

What is going on here? It seems buggy to me that the caret doesn't follow ones typing.

Behind the scenes (i.e. code-behind) I have:

```
private void PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_suppressPasswordChanged)
    {
        ((LoginFormViewModel)DataContext).Password = PasswordText.SecurePassword;
    }
}
```

`_suppressPasswordChanged` is just to avoid triggering the `PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged` handler when I explicitly set the password.

```
public void SetPassword(string password)
{
    try
    {
        _suppressPasswordChanged = true;
        PasswordText.Password = password;
    }
    finally
    {
        _suppressPasswordChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 Qs: 1) what is inside PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged. 2) any chance you are running inside a VM to see this buggy behaviour? The other day I saw similar strange typing issue with someone running a Parallels VM

Comment: break on the change event and inspect the style. see if theres anything fishy

Comment: @ProfK  You may have right to left enabled on it...just a thought

Comment: @CodingYoshi No, I don't. I especially tried enabling Left-to-Right to try and fix it, with no joy.

Comment: @Bijington Not running in a VM. Straight Windows 10 and VS 2015. Please see my edit where I added the code you ask about.

Comment: @ProfK if you stick a breakpoint in SetPassword and then type does it hit? Does SetPassword get called in any other places?

Comment: You will need to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I tested the code you posted above, minus the LoginFormViewModel, and this didn't happen.  So the problem lies in something that is not posted here.

Comment: Where is your Binding in the XAML code? Try to put a breakpoint to see if the password is somehow set as a result of updating your data. Another thing to consider is that using a `bool` for `_suppressPasswordChanged` might be fragile if in some cases, it could be set multiple times recursively as it will be set back to `false` on first `finally` block instead of last one. In WinForms, I always use integers for that purpose (usually a single one for all controls on a given form).

Comment: @Phil1970 (a) a `PasswordBox` doesn't have binding, hence so much code in the view. (b) The check for `_suppressPasswordChanged` should have been in `SetPassword`. It was still called once for each keystroke, thus resetting the caret to the beginning, even if it correctly stopped a recursive call to `PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged`. I'll post details in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MobyDisk No need, thanks for that tip though. I have a MIW (Minimal, Incomplete, and Working) answer, having just woken up with a nice clear brain. I will post it soonest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `PasswordBox` has no data binding, and thus requires code in the view to update the view-model when the user types in that box. I originally had this event handler:

```
private void PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((LoginFormViewModel)DataContext).Password = PasswordText.SecurePassword;
}
```

Then I wanted to be able to set the `Password` property in the view-model, and had to add this view method:

```
public void SetPassword(string password)
{
    PasswordText.Password = password;
}
```

Called from the setter:

```
set
{
    if (value == _password) return;
    _password = value;
    ((LoginFormPopup)View).SetPassword(_password.ToClearString());
    OnPropertyChanged();
}
```

This ended up with `SetPassword` triggering `PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged`, which called the setter again, as it should normally, but not when recursively triggered by code. My first and embarrassing attempt at preventing these methods calling each other was:

```
private bool suppressPasswordChanged;
private void PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!suppressPasswordChanged)
    {
        ((LoginFormViewModel)DataContext).Password = PasswordText.SecurePassword;
    }
}

public void SetPassword(string password)
{
    try
    {
        suppressPasswordChanged = true;
        PasswordText.Password = password;
    }
    finally
    {
        suppressPasswordChanged = false;
    }
}
```

but because `SetPassword` always reset `suppressPasswordChanged` in its `finally`, it would still always get called from `PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged`.

My current, working, but maybe slightly smelly, solution is to move the responsibility of setting the 'do-not-call' flag to the event handler:

```
private bool _textChangedEventBusy;
private void PasswordTextOnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _textChangedEventBusy = true;
        ((LoginFormViewModel)DataContext).Password = PasswordText.SecurePassword;
    }
    finally
    {
        _textChangedEventBusy = false;
    }
}

public void SetPassword(string password)
{
    if (!_textChangedEventBusy)
    {
        PasswordText.Password = password;
    }
}
```

Now, `SetPassword` is only ever called from the setter in the view-model, and then setting the caret to the beginning of the text is ideal.